# YoutubePlayer - onStateChanged event is not fired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [addEventListener in content script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776054/addeventlistener-in-content-script-not-working)

I'm making first steps to write mine first Chrome extensionm, however I have some problems with intercepting events from YoutubePlayer. The extension is a content_scripts type extension .In my js file I'm attaching event handler to "onStateChange" event of YoutubePlayer. 
The code looks like that

```
var playerLoaded = ( document.getElementById("movie_player") == null ), intervalId;

var attachEvents = function(){
    var currentVideo =document.getElementById("movie_player");
    if(currentVideo){
        currentVideo.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
         if(intervalId)
            clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}

function onytplayerStateChange() {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
};


if(!playerLoaded){
debugger;
    intervalId = setInterval(attachEvents,100);
} else{
debugger;
  attachEvents();
}
```

Unfortunatelly onytplayerStateChange function is not fired, does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this answer says

> Content scripts are executed in an isolated environment. You have to
>   inject the state method in the page itself.

Follow the advice already given there [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879)