# Message Passing issues in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to pass a message from my content script to my background page. This error occurs when the content script is executed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendRequest' of undefined
```

Content Script:

```
function injectFunction(func, exec) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "-" + func + (exec ? "()" : "");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function login() {

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });

    var d = window.mainFrame.document;
    d.getElementsByName("email")[0].value = "I need the response data here";
    d.getElementsByName("passwort")[0].value = "Here too.";
    d.forms["login"].submit();
}

injectFunction(login, true);
```

Background:

```
 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
 });
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Sephir Auto-Login",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Contact x@x.com for support or further information.",
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "icons":{
        "128":"icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["eventPage.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://somewebsite/*"],
          "js": ["login.js"]
        }, 
        {
          "matches": ["somewebsite/*"],
          "js": ["changePicture.js"]
        }
    ],
     "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Those are the examples on the documentation from google, so they *should* work.

Any help? I'm completely lost.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I'm certain that you're not using that script as a content script (perhaps an injected `<script>`?) Can you show the real significant *structure* of your code?

Comment: @RobW Thanks for your effort! I edited my whole content script into it. What do you need more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by your misunderstanding of the script executing environment. Read [Chrome extension code vs Content scripts vs Injected scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-code-vs-content-scripts-vs-injected-scripts/9916089#9916089) for more information. To be precise, you're using a form of [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) to execute code *in the context of a web page*. Web pages do not have any access to the `chrome.extension` API.

I suggest to rewrite your code to *not* use injected scripts, because it's not necessary in this case.

```
function login() {

    chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });

    var d = document.getElementById('mainFrame').contentDocument;
    d.getElementsByName("email")[0].value = "I need the response data here";
    d.getElementsByName("passwort")[0].value = "Here too.";
    d.forms["login"].submit();
}

login();
```

`*` Only works if the frame is located at the same origin. Otherwise, you need [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325415/access-iframe-content-from-a-chromes-extension-content-script/11326942#11326942) to execute code correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now a bit more. Anyways, I now get this error: Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Comment: @dislick Make sure that you use either `onMessage` + `sendMessage` *or* `onRequest` + `sendRequest`. Even though these methods have a similar signature, they are [**not** compatible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811554/chrome-extension-port-error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does/11811936#11811936).

Answer (score 1):

`sendRequest` and `onRequest` are [deprecated](http://codereview.chromium.org/9965005/). You need to use [sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage) and [onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage).

Also, you are injecting function to the DOM, that makes it run outside the content script context so `chrome.extension` API is no longer available for this function.

Comment: I adjusted my code, but it still doesn't work (same error). Thanks anyways!