# Access current tab's DOM from dynamically injected Iframe from extension & update iframe DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am developing an extension which adds a custom toolbar at the top of each page. To do this I am injecting *toolbar.html* from the extension. Since I am a beginner, I am not sure how I can access DOM elements of the current tab and how to to update the newly added iframe with the data from the current tab's DOM.

Here is the manifest:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "Extension to show custom toolbar",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background":{
      "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts":[{
      "matches":["https://bitbucket.mycompany.com/*"],
      "css":["styles.css"],
      "js":["jquery.js","myscript.js"],
      "all_frames":true
  }],
    "web_accessible_resources":[
        "toolbar.html",
        "styles.css"
    ]
}
```

Content script is *myscript.js*

```js
var url=chrome.extension.getURL('toolbar.html');
var height='35px';
var iframe="<iframe src='"+url+"' id='myCustomBar' style='height:"+height+"'></iframe>"

$('html').append(iframe);

$('body').css({
    'transform':'translateY('+height+')'
});
```

My questions are :

1. If I use a separate content script (Answered here:
   [access iframe content from a chrome's extension content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325415/access-iframe-content-from-a-chromes-extension-content-script)) for the iframe, what should be the URL matches?
2. Are there any other ways of accessing the current tab's DOM from a dynamically injected iframe?
3. Suppose I need this extension to run on all the URLs which have a URL pattern like `https://bitbucket.*.com`, what should be the matches?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use a separate content script for that iframe, since the src for the iframe is starting with `chrome-extensions://` which is not allowed to inject content scripts into by default.
2. You could include a script tag for `toolbar.html`, then use [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to do message passing between `toolbar.js` and parent content scripts.
3. According to [Match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), if `'*'` is in the host, it must be the first character. So you may want to use something like `https://*.com` and check the other parts in your code.