# How to postMessage into iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, postmessage, content-script

I am developing a Chrome extension to use with my own Web-application, processing Web-pages (including cross-domain ones), loaded into `iFrame` on my application's main page. So I have to send message, containing the URL of the page to be processed, from my main page to the content script, injected into the target `iFrame` to get access to the processed page's window.

I try to implement the approach, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326942/4007869). Below are the essential parts of all files involved:

`index.html`:

```
...
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="page_url">&nbsp;<input type="button" id="get_page" value="Get page">
    </div>
    <iframe id="cross_domain_page" src=""></iframe>
</body>
```

`base.js`:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    function pageProcessing() {
        let urlButton = window.document.getElementById("get_page");
        urlButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let url = window.document.getElementById("page_url").value;
            window.postMessage(
                {
                    sender: "get_page_button1",
                    message: url
                },
                "*"
            );
            window.postMessage(
                {
                    sender: "get_page_button2",
                    message: url
                },
                "*"
            );
        });
    }
    window.document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
            if (window.document.readyState == 'complete') {
                pageProcessing();
            }
        }
    );
})();
```

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "GetPage",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    { "js": ["main.js"], "matches": ["<all_urls>"] },
    { "js": ["frame.js"], "matches": ["<all_urls>"], "all_frames": true, "match_about_blank": true }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

`main.js`:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    window.isTop = true;
})();
```

`frame.js`:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        if (event.data &&
            event.data.sender == "get_page_button1") {
            if (window.isTop) {
                alert("Main window alert");
            } else {
                alert("Frame window alert 1");
            }
        }
    });
    if (!window.isTop) {
        window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
            if (event.data &&
                event.data.sender == "get_page_button2") {
                alert("Frame window alert 2");
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

The problem is that when I click "get_page" button the only alert I see is the main window alert. As for my understanding it means that the message, posted from the main window, does not reach the content script, injected into `iFrame`.

What is wrong with my script and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

window.postMessage in your web app sends to the main document's `window`, not to the iframe's.

Specify the iframe's window object:

```
document.getElementById('cross_domain_page').contentWindow.postMessage(.......)
```

Alternatively, you can switch to the more secure [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) messaging.

Comment: It looks strange for me that the function, working in this way, is named "POSTmessage", because it actually GETS a message for a specific window. Naming conventions are so weird sometimes. ))
But you solution works, thank you very much, @wOxxOm.

Comment: does it follow from your answer that to send message from `iFrame` back to the main window I have to use something like `if (!window.isTop) { ... window.parent.postMessage(...); }`?

Comment: Will the postMessage will work with cross-domain iframes?
I'm not able to access contentWindow of my iframe which loads cross domain page.

Comment: postMessage is designed to work with cross-origin iframes/windows. Ask a new question with [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: THANK YOU @wOxxOm! Spent so many hours on this!

Comment: This is not working for me.  The listener within the iframe is not picking up the message.

Comment: Same problem as @AkhilRavindran. 
The listener within the iframe is not picking up the message. Does it still work on chrome extensions?

Comment: Don't post a "me too" in comments. Make a new question with a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: There's something I don't understand. In the postMessage call there's the targetOrigin parameter. If we specify the target as '*' shouldn't it be sent to the iframe with the general `window.postMessage`?

Comment: @Itayst, no, postMessage sends into the object on which you call it i.e. in your example it's a `window`, which corresponds to the current environment where the code runs, not to the target.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see, thanks. So if the message is sent to the specified object, what's the purpose of the `targetOrigin` parameter?

Comment: In Web platform it's impossible to read the URL origin of a cross-origin page/frame, which is why by specifying it in postMessage you say "I expect this site to be there, do nothing otherwise".