# Pass data from electron project to iframe

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I have an electron app and inside that app I have an iframe which calls a url that runs a different react project. So I am able to send data from react project to electron project by using;

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    api? : any
  }
}

window.api.send("print", allData); // THAT WORKS
```

my **preload.js** has;

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["print", "getPrinters"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["receiptStatusBack", "printers"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

I want to send data by using something like this;

```
function sendPrintStatusToServer(result) {
    console.log("Print status: ", result)
    win.webContents.send("receiptStatusBack", result);
}
```

from electron app and catch that data from react part that works in iframe.

How can i get that data in react app ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you own the `iframe` domain? If so, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548354/how-to-postmessage-into-iframe -- If not, I think you're likely out of luck.

Comment: Thank you, yes i own the domain.  I found a way, just by using receive() function in react project worked for me. @Slbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    api? : any
  }
}

if(isElectron()) {
  window.api.receive("printers", (printerList) => {
    console.log("[PRINTER.TSX..] Printers: ", printerList);
  })
  window.api.receive("receiptStatusBack", (data) => {
    console.log("[PRINTER.TSX..] Print status: ", data);
  })
}

function isElectron() {
  // Renderer process
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.process === 'object' && window.process.type === 'renderer') {
    return true;
  }

  // Main process
  if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && typeof process.versions === 'object' && !!process.versions.electron) {
    return true;
  }

  // Detect the user agent when the `nodeIntegration` option is set to false
  if (typeof navigator === 'object' && typeof navigator.userAgent === 'string' && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Electron') >= 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```