# Why does my Chrome extension code work when inspecting elements, but not otherwise?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a Chrome extension where I am trying to skip to a specific minute on Crunchyroll, depending on whether it's filler or cannon. Strangely, when I manually inspect the 'Player0' element (the media player) and expand it through the development tools, my code works as intended. However, without manually inspecting and expanding the element, an error occurs.

I am curious to know the underlying reason for this behavior. Could someone tell me why inspecting the element makes my code work, while otherwise it fails?

When doing it by console, although all the elements are loaded in doom, if you don't manually enter inspect element and extend it doesn't work

chrome console:

```js
document.getElementById('player0').currentTime = 200
```

error:

```
VM207:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'currentTime')
    at <anonymous>:1:48
(anonymous) @   VM207:1
```

the element I am looking for does exist and is found by id="player0" in the html:

```js
<video id="player0" playsinline="" src="blob:https://static.crunchyroll.com/e6cc3673-0c06-4d6f-a8eb-b67a66445bcc" style="display: flex; height: 100%; height: 100%; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></video>
```

Edit:
Based on what I've observed, the video is embedded within an `<iframe>`, and due to "policies and security," you're not allowed to access it from a different origin. This means that there's no way for me to fast forward the time. Is there any separate approach to achieve this? The error I'm encountering is:

```js
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.crunchyroll.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:28
```

You can read more about the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: If "an error occurs", remember to talk about what that error is, ideally including showing the actual error (as code-formatted text).

Comment: I don't think `"matches"` is an expected property of `"background"`. It's possible the element does not exist when your code runs.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hi mike, I marked the error within my problem, and that's all the information the Chrome console is showing me. It doesn't provide any further details on the matter (VM207:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'currentTime')
    at <anonymous>:1:48
(anonymous) @   VM207:1)

Comment: @guest271314 It does exist, as mentioned in the issue. It works, but only when I expand it in the inspect element. And that's the weirdest part. You can even replicate it by entering a random anime on Crunchyroll and testing it with the code I provided in my question.

Comment: What triggers your code? Are you listening for a ready event for the video or the document?

Comment: Can you show the actual code that's failing in your post, with a bit more than just one line? (ideally, [mcve] form)

Comment: Is your content script running in an `"ISOLATED"` context? Looks like from your manifest. It's possible the element does not exist when your code runs. Try including `"run_at":"document_end"` in your manifest.

Comment: @NickSlash What document.getElementById('player0').currentTime = 200 does is advance the video to a specific minute (200 seconds in this case).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The purpose of that code line is for you to test it through the "inspect element" console in Google Chrome. I have a code that waits for the elements to load in the DOM, but the function is the same as if you were to do it directly from the console.

Comment: Yes. I understand that, I was wondering what causes that code to execute. You say the player exists, but it might not exist (or be ready) when you are trying to run your code

Comment: And what is the code that waits for the element to load in the DOM? Because you cannot reproduce the timing of an extension in the dev console after the page has already finished loading. Using the console to check if something's there doesn't tell us anything about whether that element can be found when your extension code runs.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think this code (https://github.com/rquitales/crunchyroll-intro-skipper/blob/main/src/content_script.ts) may clarify things a bit more. I based mine on it. The only difference is that it checks if the player0 element is already loaded, but that never happens. However, when I enter the console and expand the elements, it works perfectly. P.S.: This GitHub repository no longer works, presumably for the same reason I'm experiencing.

Comment: @NickSlash My assumption is that Google may have some barrier preventing my extension from manipulating the video timeline. Even if I wait in the DOM or create a loop, it doesn't work unless I do it through the console and expand the elements in Chrome. I already extract the anime title and chapter name by waiting for these elements to load. Strangely, this is the only thing that fails, and it's as if it doesn't exist

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Based on what I've observed, the video is embedded within an `<iframe>`, and due to "policies and security," you're not allowed to access it from a different origin. This means that there's no way for me to fast forward the time. Is there any separate approach to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325415/access-iframe-content-from-a-chromes-extension-content-script might be what you're looking for (even if it's not the answer you were hoping for)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access the player inside the parent document with...

```
document.getElementById('player0').currentTime = 200
```

...but you said the player is inside an iframe of this document, therefore it should be...

```
Iframe_ID.contentWindow.document.player0.currentTime = 200;
```

To make it easier for you to manipulate the player set up an identifier for it like this:

```
var V=Iframe_ID.contentWindow.document.player0;
```

And now you can just...

```
V.play();

V.pause();

V.stop();

V.currentTime = 200;
```

And so forth...

If you don't know the ID of the iframe then just use...

```
var Iframe_ID=document.getElementsByTagName('IFRAME')[0];
```

...assuming it's the first iframe in the document.

Comment: did you use ChatGPT for this? `var` hasn't been a JS thing since `let` and `const` landed, years ago, and `iframe_ID` or `V` don't follow JS naming conventions. At all.

Comment: Is that the best you've got? :) Let is NOT a replacement for VAR... read up on it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Those aren’t things that point to ChatGPT, are they?

Comment: I have no idea what ChatGPT is... :)

Comment: @Ry it is when it's trained on old JS and JS-likes and the person trying to get some quick rep doesn't bother specifying much. It's basically far enough away from actual JS as to either be written by someone who doesn't know JS, or an AI generator =)

Comment: Well I reckon hating a contributor’s identifiers warrants a down-vote… you might want to look into that.

Comment: (That said, `let` *is* a replacement for `var`, and you should use it. Not sure what you thought it was.)