# jQuery.trigger('click') doesn't work in Chrome Extension on Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

since my Chrome Extension didn't work under Mac I broke the code down and found the problem:

*background.js*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    alert("Goin to");
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "script.js"});
});
```

*script.js*

```
$('#Hoster_30').trigger('click');
alert("Clicked");
```

jQuery is loaded and both alerts are shown, but the click event isn't triggered. It works fine when I directly enter the trigger in the js console on the page and under Windows it also works in the add on.

Here my *manifest.json*

```
{
    "name": "MacAddon",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },  
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "MacAddon"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.kinox.to/*", "http://*.streamcloud.eu/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js"]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should have edited your previous question, to include the code (not create a new one). But good job, you've now created a demo to reproduce the problem. That's what we, SO users, like to see,

Comment: On which page are you testing the extension? Neither `http://kinox.to/` nor `http://streamcloud.eu/` have an element with ID `Hoster_30`.

Comment: http://www.kinox.to/Stream/Die_Simpsons.html every movie and serial has a Hoster_30

Comment: `$('#Hoster_30').data('events').click[0].handler` showed me that the following code is executed: ` getPlayerByMirror(this,'Auto');`. Is the problem solved if you directly call this function, with `this` being the element? Since the function is defined in the page, you have to inject the script to test it. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9602022?chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message

Comment: No, this doesn't work, but `getPlayerByMirror($('#Hoster_30'), 'Auto')` worked. Thanks, I'll use that for now but If anybody has an Idea why the click Event only worked under Windows would be nice

Comment: That was exactely what I suggested. Which Chrome and OSX version are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.6.8 and was using Chrome 18. The jQuery.trigger works from Chrome 20+ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Chrome 19-, you have to [inject the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) and use the website's own method to switch the Episode.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = "getPlayerByMirror($('#Hoster_30'), 'Auto');";
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

(To find out which function had to be called, I [inspected the `$().data('events')` object in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/571087): `$('#Hoster_30').data('events').click[0].handler`).
In Chrome 20+, using `.trigger('click')` from the content script worked fine:

```
$('#Hoster_30').trigger('click');
```

Thanks [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w). for welcoming me so greatly here and [answering the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709940/jquery-triggerclick-doesnt-work-in-chrome-extension-on-mac#comment15533043_11709940)!

Comment: Didn't work for me, Alternatively I used native createEvent and dispatchEvent