# Is there some way to store information for Google Chrome extensions in on google servers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Now I save settings in localStorage, but when the same user open browser on another computer and login in google she get extensions, but don't get extensions settings, which was made before on first computer. Is there way to synchronize it without rising own servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Chrome.Storage.Sync See my answer on this question for more details: [Access extension data on other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284952/access-extension-data-on-other-pages/12290000#12290000). You do have to be careful how much data you store there though as the limits can be a bit restrictive. See the developer documentation for more info: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html