# Can the window object be modified from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a Chrome extension that provides a new object inside `window`. When a web page is viewed in a browser with the extension loaded, I would like `window.mything` to be available via Javascript. The `window.mything` object will have some functions that I will define in the extension, and these functions should be callable from `console.log` or any Javascript file when the page is viewed in a browser with the extension enabled.

I was able to successfully inject a Javascript file into the page by using a [Content Script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

```
var s = document.createElement("script"); 
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("mything.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

mything.js looks like this:

```
window.mything = {thing: true};
console.log(window);
```

Whenever a page loads, I see the entire `window` object as I expect it to be in the console. However, I can't interact with the `window.mything` object from the console. It seems at if the injected script hasn't really modified the global `window` object.

How can I modify the global `window` object from a Chrome extension?

Comment: That's impossible. Are you viewing the right console, is the script really executed (inspect document and look for script tag / check for syntax errors)? The script certainly runs in the context of the page, and therefore, `mything` must be existent.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can't, not directly.  From the [content scripts documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - **Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts**

(emphasis added)

The `window` object the content script sees is not the same `window` object that the page sees.

You can pass messages via the DOM, however, by using the `window.postMessage` method.  Both your page and content script listen to the **message** event, and whenever you call `window.postMessage` from one of those places, the other will receive it.  There's an [example of this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) on the "Content Scripts" documentation page.

edit:
You could potentially add some methods to the page by injecting a script from the content script.  It still wouldn't be able to communicate back with the rest of the extension though, without using something like `postMessage`, but you could at least add some things to the page's `window`

```
var elt = document.createElement("script");
elt.innerHTML = "window.foo = {bar:function(){/*whatever*/}};"
document.head.appendChild(elt);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use your suggestion verbatim, but the concept helped me zero in on the real issue.

Comment: U can also use eval("window.foo = {bar:function(){/*whatever*/}};");

Comment: The `<script>` element hack worked perfectly. I'm curious, are these Javascript tags executed as soon as they are added to `<head>`, even if the page is already loaded?

Comment: If it's inline script, ie `<script>//do something</script>` then yes, it's executed immediately (synchronously).  If it's a remote script `<script src="foo.js"></script>` then it will be executed after the script is downloaded.  Prior to the addition of the `async` tag this would be a common way to prevent a script download from blocking the page rendering.

Comment: You can modify the `window` object using it's own mutators like `addEventListener`. No need for Document element injection.

Answer (score 29):

After hours trying different attempts and facing security issues like CORS, I found ways to edit the `window` object on `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Safari`. You need to use different strategies for each one:

### Chrome

1. Add your script to `content_scripts`.
2. Inside your script file, append a `script` to the page and make it run your custom code inline. Like this:

```js
;(function() {
  function script() {
    // your main code here
    window.foo = 'bar'
  }

  function inject(fn) {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.text = `(${fn.toString()})();`
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script)
  }

  inject(script)
})()
```

### Firefox

On Firefox, the solution above doesn't work due to a `Content-Security-Policy` error. But the following workaround is currently working, at least for now:

1. Add 2 scripts to `content_scripts`, e.g. `inject.js` and `script.js`
2. The `inject` script will get the full **absolute url** of the `script.js` file and load it:

```js
;(function() {
  const b = typeof browser !== 'undefined' ? browser : chrome

  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = b.runtime.getURL('script.js')
  document.documentElement.appendChild(script)
})()
```

3. Your `script.js` will contain your main code:

```js
;(function() {
  // your main code here
  window.foo = 'bar'
})()
```

### Safari

It's very similar to Firefox.

1. Create 2 javascript files, e.g. `inject.js` and `script.js`
2. The `inject` script will get the full **absolute url** of the `script.js` file and load it:

```js
;(function() {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = safari.extension.baseURI + 'script.js'
  document.documentElement.appendChild(script)
})()
```

3. Your `script.js` will contain your main code:

```js
;(function() {
  // your main code here
  window.foo = 'bar'
})()
```

### Source code

See full code here: https://github.com/brunolemos/simplified-twitter

Comment: I managed in firefox using the cloneInto command: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.cloneInto Sadly this doesn't work in Chrome...

Comment: thanks fro the solution, is this secure? or is there any other secure way?

Comment: this is fail with `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-2hqy/01Xj3kkdA60wVjY8N6m2WXv5URv1rhk3jCDyHY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
`

Answer (score 16):

As others have pointed out, context scripts do not run in the same context as the page's, so, to access the correct `window`, you need to inject code into the page.

Here's my take at it:

```
function codeToInject() {
    // Do here whatever your script requires. For example:
    window.foo = "bar";
}

function embed(fn) {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.text = `(${fn.toString()})();`;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}

embed(codeToInject);
```

Clean and easy to use. Whatever you need to run in the page's context, put it in `codeToInject()` (you may call it whatever you prefer). The `embed()` function takes care of packaging your function and sending it to run in the page.

What the `embed()` function does is to create a `script` tag in the page and embed the function `codeToInject()` into it as an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). The browser will immediately execute the new `script` tag as soon as it's appended to the document and your injected code will run in the context of the page, as intended.

Answer (score 10):

A chrome extension's `content_script` runs within its own context which is separate from the window. You can inject a script into the page though so it runs in the same context as the page's window, like this: [Chrome extension - retrieving global variable from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-global-variable-from-webpage#answer-9636008)

I was able to call methods on the window object and modify window properties by essentially adding a `script.js` to the page's DOM:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    s.remove();
};
```

and creating custom event listeners in that injected script file:

```
document.addEventListener('_my_custom_event', function(e) {
  // do whatever you'd like! Like access the window obj
  window.myData = e.detail.my_event_data;
})
```

and dispatching that event in the content_script:

```
var foo = 'bar'
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('_save_OG_Editor', {
  'detail': {
    'my_event_data': foo
  }
}))
```

or vice versa; dispatch events in `script.js` and listen for them in your extension's content_script (like the above link illustrates well).

Just be sure to add your injected script within your extension's files, and add the script file's path to your [manifest within `"web_accessible_resources"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) or you'll get an error.

Hope that helps someone \ (•◡•) /

Answer (score 6):

I've been playing around with this. I found that I can interact with the window object of the browser by wrapping my javascript into a window.location= call.

```
var myInjectedJs = "window.foo='This exists in the \'real\' window object';"
window.location = "javascript:" + myInjectedJs;

var myInjectedJs2 = "window.bar='So does this.';"
window.location = "javascript:" + myInjectedJs2;
```

It works, but only for the last instance of window.location being set. If you access the document's window object, it will have a variable "bar" but not "foo"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the other answers here, this is what I'm using:

```
((source)=>{
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.text = `(${source.toString()})();`;
  document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
})(function (){

  // Your code here
  // ...

})
```

Works great, no issues.

Answer (score -2):

Content Scripts **can** call `window` methods which can then be used to mutate the `window` object. This is easier than `<script>` tag injection and works even when the `<head>` and `<body>` haven't yet been parsed (e.g. when using `run_at: document_start`).

```
// In Content Script
window.addEventListener('load', loadEvent => {
    let window = loadEvent.currentTarget;
    window.document.title='You changed me!';
});
```

Comment: This seems to only work for existing variables not for new ones, can someone verify this?

Comment: this window object that is referred in this script is part of the content script and not the embedding page so is not the correct solution to the question

Comment: Extension and page use different contexts, this answer is misleading.