# Chrome Extension can modify Window object but can't create new variable

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium Webdriver (JavaScript Version) and a Chrome Extension to capture network traffic and look for traffic to a specific pattered url. I'm trying to save the matching traffic to a new variable in the window object to simplify testing later.

I can modify the window following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395722/can-the-window-object-be-modified-from-a-chrome-extension) but for some reason I cannot create a new global variable, so when I open the console and type in "window.testing" after the page load it returns undefined.

Content script code snippet:

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadEvent => {
    let window = loadEvent.currentTarget;
    //Works as expected
    window.document.title='You changed me!';

    window.testing = {test: '123'};
    testing.customlog = 'You made a custom log!';

    // Console logs as expected
    console.log(testing);

    // Gives error - undefined
    console.log(window.testing);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HTTP is stateless, every time you load the page it will use the initial values of whatever you set in JavaScript. You can't set a global variable in JS and simply make that value stay after loading the page again.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)