# bypass CSP in Chrome extension's content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm working on Chrome extension, that need to work with another extension (Metamask).

Standard way of doing this is by `window.ethereum` object, but from content script this object is undefined.

I found [Can the window object be modified from a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395722/can-the-window-object-be-modified-from-a-chrome-extension) but all examples are blocked by CSP of website (in my case twitter.com)

Is there any way of bypassing CSP from chrome extension's context?

Comment: [Access global js variables from js injected by a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005)