# How to get errors stack trace in Chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There is a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd) with `content script` that handles JS errors occured on all tabs pages. But the problem is that no one of usual methods of getting errors stack trace does not work.

For example, there is a code in `content script` of Chrome extension:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
    console.log(event.error.stack); // event.error will be null
}, false);
```

If I call this code inside web page, so `event.error` will contains `Error` object with `stack` property.

Same problem with trying to get stack trace using:

```
console.log((new Error()).stack));
```

Does anybody knows some working issue to get error stack trace inside `content script` of Chrome extension?

Error stack trace must be received as `string` or `Array`, means not just like some output in JS console by calling `console.trace()`.

**How to reproduce**:

1. Download https://mega.co.nz/#!ENw00YAC!92gBZEoLCO9jPsWyKht4dbjYyo0Zk-PU5YAj0h88-3Q
2. Unpack `jzen.zip` to some `/jsen` folder
3. Open `chrome://extensions` in your Google Chrome, enable `Developer mode` https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLwpa.png
4. Click `Load unpacked extension` button and select path to `/jsen` folder
5. Open `/jsen/content.js` file and add `console.log('JSEN', e.error.stack);` inside `window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {`
6. Go to http://xpart.ru/_share/js.htm and see result in JS console(Ctrl+Shift+J)
7. Try to edit `/jsen/content.js` to get correct error trace
8. To reinitialize Chrome extension source code click https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LIEa.png

Comment: You should mention that you want the stack trace as a string, it is not enough to have it displayed in the console. The question is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you mention, the `error` property of the event object is `null` when capturing the event in Content Script context, but it has the required info when captured in webpage context. So the solution is to capture the event in webpage context and use messaging to deliver it to the Content Script.

```
// This code will be injected to run in webpage context
function codeToInject() {
    window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        var error = {
            stack: e.error.stack
            // Add here any other properties you need, like e.filename, etc...
        };
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ReportError', {detail:error}));
    });
}

document.addEventListener('ReportError', function(e) {
    console.log('CONTENT SCRIPT', e.detail.stack);
});

//Inject code
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = '(' + codeToInject + '())';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

The techniques used are described in:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/1507998
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636008/1507998

Comment: +1 You beat me by 6 mins with a probably more robust answer. Impressive how Rob has already posted great, detailed answers on any **future** Chrome-Extension-related questions :)

Comment: Is this answer still valid in Chrome? After trying both solutions to the T, the event.error object is still null.

Comment: @jsutton yes, I just tested it on 42.0.2311.152 m and it works.

Comment: I have a slightly specific issue: this implementation works for me with a local html file with my script in between `<script>` tags, although when I separate my js into a separate local file and use `<script src="script.js">`, I can no longer listen for errors and instead get this in my console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null`. But, when I upload my html and js files to my webserver via ftp, the implementation works online on my website. any idea why I can't read the stack locally?

Comment: actually, it looks like once on my server, the contents of my external script are added into the webpage onload, whereas locally, they aren't. i.e. the javascript is not rendered into the html when developing locally

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem

The main problem is ***[JS context isolation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)***, i.e. the fact that *"Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world".* This is a good thing, of course, because it avoids conflicts and enhances security, but yet a problem if you want to catch errors.

> Each isolated world sees its own version of the (window) object. Assigning to the object affects your independent copy of the object...
>
> ...neither one can read the other's event handler. The event handlers are called in the order in which they were assigned.

---

#### A solution

On posiible solution (a.k.a. hack) consists of the following steps:

1. Inject some code into the web-page itself (and try to make is as non-obtrusive as possible to avoid conflicts).
2. In that code register an event listener for errors and store the error data in a DOM-node's **[dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset)**.
3. Finally, from within the content script, use a **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** to watch for changes in this DOM-node's attributes.
4. Once a change in the specified *data-<...>* attribute is detected, grab its new value and there you have your error info right in your content script :)

---

#### The source code

Below is the source code of a sample extension that does exactly that.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_start",
        "all_frames": true
    }],
}
```

**content.js**:

```
/* This <script> element will function as an "error-proxy" 
 * for the content-script */
var errorProxy = document.createElement('script');
errorProxy.id = 'myErrorProxyScriptID';
errorProxy.dataset.lastError = '';

/* Make the content as non-obtrusive as possible */
errorProxy.textContent = [
    '',
    '(function() {',
    '    var script = document.querySelector("script#' + errorProxy.id + '");',
    '    window.addEventListener("error", function(evt) {',
    '        script.dataset.lastError = evt.error.stack;',
    '    }, true);',
    '})();',
    ''].join('\n');

/* Add the <script> element to the DOM */
document.documentElement.appendChild(errorProxy);

/* Create an observer for `errorProxy`'s attributes
 * (the `data-last-error` attribute is of interest) */
var errorObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if ((mutation.type === 'attributes')
                && (mutation.attributeName === 'data-last-error')) {
            console.log('Content script detected new error:\n',
                        errorProxy.dataset.lastError);
        }
    });
});
errorObserver.observe(errorProxy, { attributes: true });
```

Comment: thank you for one more working solution with such a detailed description. Looks like you're really good Expert! :)