# Get The Data Of JavaScript Console With Error Message And Line number and send it to server through Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome-extension

I want to get all the data through the console window of the browser
1) Error messages
2) File name with Line Number.
I tried a lot. Search it but cant find any solution. I tried many Api's but couldn't get any solution.
Error, stack trace, console and many other thing which i have tried but couldn't get the data.
I want to get The data from browser console just JavaScript errors. and want to send it to server through Ajax call.

Comment: You should give some examples of what you have tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get errors stack trace in Chrome extension content script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323600/how-to-get-errors-stack-trace-in-chrome-extension-content-script)