# How to access all the data shown in the chrome console "the ones fired by browser itself" using JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to be able to access and save all the data shown in the chrome console, I don't want to have only the data shown when you use console.log() or console.error(), but the ones that fire from the browser itself when for example an image failed to load.

I have searched and all solution were regarding shadowing the log() warn() error() info() console functions. This solution will not help me because these are not all the data shown in the console.

All I need is as easy as I can right click the console and hit save as and I got a file containing every thing in this log, I want to be able to have a stream or object from the js the client side.

Finally using --enable-logging --v=1 to save a file inside my directory will not help also, I want to have this data from the client side as stream or object

Comment: There's no way to capture all messages. The closest thing is `chrome.debugger` API but it won't see some of the messages either and it has other downsides as well.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I will check it but there are some applications that actually capture all the data shown in the console. doing this should be easy as you can right click and save it.

Comment: They use the standard means listed in that answer. There are no other ways.  The only thing it doesn't mention explicitly is a listener for `error` event, I'll add it soon. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323600/how-to-get-errors-stack-trace-in-chrome-extension-content-script) a partially correct example, meanwhile.

Comment: Yes I think listener on error event will help, this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd do exactly what I want to achieve