# Communicating with injected .js files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm trying to make a simple Chrome extension that controls Youtube.
I injected the script that directly controls Youtube with Method 1 of 
[Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879). This is how the injected script looks like.

**control.js**

```
var player = document.getElementById("movie_player");

//Do something

document.addEventListener('Remote2Buffer', function(e){
    alert(e.detail);
});
```

And on a content_script file named buffer.js, I wanted control.js to receive information from it. So I sent the 'Remote2Buffer' event from buffer.js. But the alert that's on control.js isn't working, which implies that the data wasn't sent as intended. This is what buffer.js looks like.

**buffer.js**

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('control.js');
s.onload = function(){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

var send ='plz work';
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('Remote2Buffer', {detail: send}));
```

Is there a possible way to send data to a injected js file from a content_script .js file, or any other way?

TL;DR:  I'm trying to send data to a injected .js file.(The opposite direction of data transmission shown on [Chrome extension - retrieving Gmail's original message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message/9636008#9636008).) Is it possible? If possible, how should I?

**EDIT** : I changed buffer.js to

**buffer.js**

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('control.js');
s.onload = function(){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

var send ='plz work';
window.onload = function(){
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('Remote2Buffer', {detail: send}));
};
```

After changing the code, the alert started to occur, but sometimes it didn't occur. Why does this happen?

Comment: Why do you use DOM Events at all? You can just have `buffer.js` detect `control.js` and have them communicate directly.

Comment: @Halcyon They are in different execution contexts and cannot communicate directly.

Comment: I see. Maybe this is really trivial but you seem to be dispatching the event before `control.js` had it's onload. Can you move the last 3 lines into the `onload` callback?

Comment: @Xan removing a `<script>` tag after it has executed has absolutely no efect on the execution environment.

Comment: @Halcyon I put the last 2 lines of buffer.js into window.onload, and  the alert is behaving rather strange. Sometimes the alert comes out, and sometimes it doesn't. Do i have to change window to something else? Sorry for the rather stupid question because I'm new to this language:(.