# Exchanging events between React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm making a Chrome extension that inserts 2 different React extensions on to the page. I'd like to keep each of them in sync by sending the 2nd one an event with appropriate data when something else is selected in the first one.

Is there a best practice when it comes to sending events to other components?

I tried this from the first:

```
evt = new CustomEvent("selectedEmailChange", {
  detail: {
    email: data.email
  }
});
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

And then in the 2nd:

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.listenForEmailChange();
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener("selectedEmailChange", this.handleEmailChange, false);
  },
  listenForEmailChange: function() {
    window.addEventListener("selectedEmailChange", this.handleEmailChange, false);
  },
  handleEmailchange: function() {
    debugger
    console.log("i heard you dog!");
  },
```

But nothing's being caught in the 2nd.

Comment: Looks like subscribing to events in componentDidMount is the best practice... http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: try window.postMessage instead - I'm guessing as an extension you cannot publish a message like that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message/9636008#9636008

Comment: @pherris i use it communicate with the host page in other places and it definitely works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaaah! `handleEmailchange` should be `handleEmailChange` (capital 'C').