How to intergrate with current viewer ACC?
I have a question relate to access data viewer form ACC.
Can we get data from current viewer of ACC ? I don't want create another forge viewer to develop. I want override with current viewer in Autodesk Construction Cloud.
My idea is intergrate direct with ACC viewer

It look like we develop a chrome or firefox extension to modify or custom ACC interface. I can add some extenstion inside current viewer no need create any another app viewer.
Any help appreciated !

global viewer reference is NOP_VIEWER, you can use it like this:
NOP_VIEWER.model.getData()

The NOP_VIEWER reference is just for debugging purposes but can be used in the chrome extension.

Thank you for your help, that is what I'm trying to find.

Hi @varunpatil , as I know it is imposible to intergrate to chrome extension :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644906/accessing-all-the-window-variables-of-the-current-tab-in-chrome-extension

There's no direct way, it takes some extra work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-global-variable-from-webpage/9636008#9636008
