# Activating browser addons through web-code

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Just a short question. Is there a way to activate chrome extensions through the use of a webpage button? I am trying to make a button on a site that will activate an extension when clicked and disable them when clicked again. Is there a solution for this?

I have been trying to find a solution and the only thing that seems to work is to create my own extension.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `activating`. If the extension is not disabled on chrome://extensions page then `postMessage` or `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` might be an answer, for example: [Chrome extension - retrieving Gmail's original message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14656720)

Comment: Take the proxy service Hola for example. I'd like to press a button on my webpage that would turn it on. As in, start a proxy for me.

Comment: In Firefox (because of your addon tag) you can create a custom message and dispatch it on the window. And in the addon it should be setup to listen for that event.