# Send messages from contentScript to injectedScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For some reason the injected script will not get what the content script is sending it.

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ToFBScript',{detail: {data: "Hello    World"}}));

//Injecting Script
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('fbscriptforextension.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function(){
 s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};
```

My contentScript

```
var storage;
document.addEventListener('ToFBScript',function(e){
storage = e.detail.data;
console.log(storage);
});
```

My Injected Script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension - retrieving Gmail's original message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message)

Comment: Besides above link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-code-vs-content-scripts-vs-injected-scripts also could help understand content scripts vs injected scripts.

Comment: Quick note: your last 2 edits invalidated my answer. Editing a question substantially AFTER you receive answers is usually a bad idea; I would ask you to roll those back and ask a new question if you still have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the `data` property of [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent), but you can only set `detail`. Fortunately, you can set it to anything JSON-serializable.

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ToFBScript', {detail: {data: g}}));

/* ... */

document.addEventListener('ToFBScript', function(e) {
  storage = e.detail.data;
}
```

Comment: I have done this and put console.log(storage); withing the event listener in the injected script, but nothing even prints out and I think that for some reason the injected script is just not getting the event.  Could it have to do with when each script loads or is injected?

Comment: I edited my code above show the block of code for content script shows the injection of the injected script

Comment: Well, _duh_, you're dispatching the event way before anything can listen to it. You need to move messaging code to the `onload` handler.

Comment: Ahhh okay, thank you! But one more question, I want to store the e.detail.data into a variable inside of the document.addEventListener, and I already declared the variable outside the document.addEventListener() but whenever I try to print storage out outside of the document.addEventListener() it is undefined and acts as if storage = e.detail.data; never happened once outside the document.addEventListener()