# window.functionName is undefined in my code while it is defined in the developer tool console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I've tried delaying the code even if I execute window.functionName in the console before the code actually finishes it, I still get the same outcome (works when I directly enter `window.functionName` in the console but not when being executed from the javascript code).

Note this is all happening in the content-script of a chrome extension.

For full context, I have a Vue component which has a method that calls a function in another javascript file which eventually calls window.functionName -- so something like this:

**SomeVueComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click="buttonClicked">
</template>
<script>
  import { doSomething } from 'do-something.js';
   
  export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        buttonClicked() {
          doSomething();
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**do-something.js**

```
export function doSomething() {
  doFunctionName() {
     window.functionName(); // Returns "Uncaught ReferenceError: functionName is not defined"
  }
  ...
  whenElementIsShown() {
    // When the element was shown a script was injected to the page that sets window.functionName 
    // to something. I tried putting doFunctionName in a timeout and got the same results.
    doFunctionName();
  }
  
}
```

**Whereas in the developer tools console...**

```
window.functionName() // Returns "f (){...}"
```

I'm just not sure why `window` would be different in the two cases. Is it because of Vue? Is it some scoping issue? Is there a way to get the most recently updated `window`?

Comment: How does the call to `doSomething()` work? I can't see from your example how the button call ends up calling `whenElementIsShown` so that the function would be available in `window`.

Comment: in the vue component when the button is clicked it calls the method `buttonClicked()`which calls `doSomething()` and then do something does stuff to the dom that ends up causing an element to show up. When that happens, a script is injected to the page that sets window.functionName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the window variable in the chrome extension is different than the page's window variable. More info here: [Chrome extension - retrieving global variable from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-global-variable-from-webpage/9636008#9636008)