# Send a message from dynamically added script to parent chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have Script.js file which added to the youtube page dynamically through this code:

```
   var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('Script.js');
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function () {
        s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
    };
```

I have two questions :
1- how I can send a message from inserted file to a parent chrome extension. 
2- how I can make a cross-origin request from the inserted file..It's display error message in the console

```
Origin http://www.youtube.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`postMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) or custom events ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779769/938089?call-background-function-of-chrome-extension-from-a-site), [reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7597826/938089?invoking-a-google-chrome-extension-from-javascript), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636008/938089?chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message)).
2. After adding the [permission](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) to the manifest, you can initiate cross-site requests from Content scripts. Use one of the methods from step 1 to call the Content script from the web page. Make sure that you only request the necessary permissions (eg not `*://*/*` if you do not need to access all URLs) and validate all input (so that malicious pages cannot abuse your extension).